# Vlookup in M language and sum values

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

In trying to make a Vlookup on PowerQuery that also makes a sum of the multiple values fond. I have 2 tables on my Power BI that are conected by the Report Number as showed below. I need to create a new column on table B that gets the sum of cost at Table A according to their report numbers.

[image]

At Power Query I have created a new Column on **Table B** using the following code:

[image]

After that I was planning to simply create a new column summing the list result, but my list is *Empty* and I can't realize why. Can anyone help me understand why I can't get the results?

I can't do this using DAX, it should be in M

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to add the column into TableB is:

```
= (i)=>List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(TableA, each [Report Num]=i[Report Num]) [Cost])
```

Another way is to Group TableA and merge it in. I tend to think this is a faster method for larger tables

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableB"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(TableA, {"Report Num"}, {{"Cost", each List.Sum([Cost]), type number}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"Report Num"},  #"Grouped Rows", {"Report Num"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"Cost"}, {"Cost"})
in  #"Expanded Table1"
```

of course, if those are the only two columns in TableB, you could just create the whole table in one go

```
let Source =  Table.Group(TableA, {"Report Num"}, {{"Cost", each List.Sum([Cost]), type number}})
in Source
```

Comment: I Tried but still gets me null as result. Don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Which one did you try ? Are you using the correct names for the Queries and the columns? Case (upper/lower) matters in M.  Post a screenshot of the exact view of TableA and Table B and your code in table B

Comment: It worked! In fact I was using columns formated as Text and Numbers. Now it worked perfectly! Thanks!